# Use closed camera shutter as a view background

Tags: ios, background, camera

I'm building an AR application for iPhone, which of course extensively use the camera view.

I would like to use the native camera shutter image (closed) as a background for some view.

My question:

Is it a problem to use it? Or could it be a rejection reason?

Answer (score 1):

I got my answer:

The app i was working on is using the closed shutter of the camera as a background for one of its screen.
We've submitted it successfully to the store.

No problem to use the native camera shutter as a background in your apps.